# What is the difference between the Unision options `prefer=newer` and `force=newer`?

Tags: synchronization, unison

A piece of the Unison manual for `force`:

> You can also specify `-force newer` (or `-force older`) to force Unison to choose the file with the later (earlier) modtime. In this case, the `-times` preference must also be enabled.

My understanding is that when conflict occurs the more recent file version is taken. But there is other option `prefer` and it may be set to `newer` as well.  Unfortunately description for `prefer` is meager so I have no idea what `prefer=newer` means and what the difference is?

Answer (score 3):

## Prefer Newer

Your understanding is not quite complete. When versions of a file are detected to be different, *and one of those files is just an updated version of the other,* Unison will copy the newer one over the other one.

Now what if you updated each version of single file on two machines without syncing in between the edits? Neither file is an updated version of the other, so it's ambiguous to Unison which one to keep. These files are said to be [in conflict](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#conflicts), and Unison will prompt you to choose a file (or if you have `auto true` set Unison will just skip that file). The `prefer newer` option will tell Unison to not be conflicted in cases like this, and just assume the file with the most recent timestamp is the one you want to have synced. This is important if you want Unison to run in the background, with options like `auto true` and `repeat watch`. Here's the relevant explanation of `prefer` from the manual, and note that it only matters if path or file is in conflict:

> **prefer xxx**
>
> Including the preference `-prefer root` causes Unison always to resolve conflicts in favor of `root`, rather than asking for guidance from the user. (The syntax of `root` is the same as for the `root` preference, plus the special values newer and older.)
>
> This preference is overridden by the `preferpartial` preference.
>
> This preference should be used only if you are sure you know what you are doing!

## Force Newer

For `force newer`, it looks like you missed the line in the manual right before line you quoted:

> Including the preference `force root` causes Unison to resolve all differences (even non-conflicting changes) in favor of root. This effectively changes Unison from a synchronizer into a mirroring utility.

So while the `prefer` option just syncs a file if there was a conflict (in particular if the file has changed), `force` will sync *everything* regardless of whether there have been changes.

Comment: "force will sync everything regardless of whether there have been changes." If nothing changed, what is being synced? Do you have an example scenario where these options would be produce different results?